# data-toggle=“collapse” with multiple triggers /bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, triggers

I have four menus, *I used collapse fuction from bootstrap*, and each one with its own content.

Is there a way to show only the content of the selected button/menu and collapse/hide the others??

thank you

```
<div class="row example-row example-thumbnails">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
<div class="thumbnail"><img alt="A - Standard Tip Profile" src="images/products/mm/metal-type/standard-metal-type.png" />
<div class="caption">
<h3>A - STANDARD TIP PROFILE</h3>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#order-online-tungsten">Click here</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
<div class="thumbnail"><img alt="H - Heat Treated Tapered Tip Profile" src="images/products/mm/metal-type/heat-metal-type.png" />
<div class="caption">
<h3>H - HEAT TREATED TAPERED TIP PROFILE</h3>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#order-online-heat">Click here</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
<div class="thumbnail"><img alt="B - Blunted Tip Profile" src="images/products/mm/metal-type/blunted-metal-type.png" />
<div class="caption">
<h3>B - BLUNTED TIP PROFILE</h3>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#order-online-blunted">Click here</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
<div class="thumbnail"><img alt="F - Extra Fine Tip Profile" src="images/products/mm/metal-type/extra-metal-type.png" />
<div class="caption">
<h3>F - EXTRA FINE TIP PROFILE</h3>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#order-online-extra">Click here</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and my four content divs:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 collapse" id="order-online-tungsten">
content
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 collapse" id="order-online-extra">
content
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 collapse" id="order-online-blunted">
content
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 collapse" id="order-online-heat">
content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery you can achieve this pretty easily:

Add the following to collapse all other sections and only open the one selected on click:

```
$('.example-thumbnails button').on('click', function() {
  $('.collapse').removeClass('in');
});
```

This click action removes the 'in' class from the collapsable sections, which is the trigger that makes them appear in your example. The selectors I used could be modified if they conflict with future buttons dropped into the .example-thumbnails div.

Here's a pen to show it at work:

http://codepen.io/mutualdesigns/pen/AXYzbV

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help!

Comment: Hi Mutual Designs, 
I try to implement this in my joomla website, I create a JS file, and I made the call, but with an error:
`code`collapse-in.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`code`

How can i solve this problem?
thank you

Comment: You've got a <code> tag in that JS file somewhere. Make sure it's out of there.

Comment: Hi Mutual, 
that was an error while trying to add the code here, use wrong code label, the message that I have when running the script is: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Thank you for your time

Comment: I'd have to see the code you're trying to post to help. You've got something in your JS file that doesn't belong there. Try posting it to pastebin.com or codepen.io.